# ¿como muestro las claves y valores de un diccionario por linea y en orden? python

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo un problema a la hora de mostrar las claves y valores de un diccionario por linea. Lo que quiero es que se imprima en la primer linea, la primer clave y su valor, en la segunda linea la segunda clave y su valor, etc.

Luego como segundo objetivo, como se podría hacer lo mismo que antes pero ordenándolos de mayor a menor según el valor de cada clave (cantidad de votos en el ejercicio)??

Este es mi código, es un ejercicio con "partido político" y "numero de votos":

```
partido_y_votos = {}
continuar = "s"
while continuar == "s":
    partido_politico = input("ingrese partido politico: ")
    cantidad_votos = int(input("ingrese cantidad de votos del partido: "))

    # agrega el nombre del partido y sus votos al diccionario.
    # si el nombre se repite, se suman los votos ingresados

    if partido_politico in partido_y_votos:
        partido_y_votos[partido_politico] += cantidad_votos
    else:
        partido_y_votos[partido_politico] = cantidad_votos
    continuar = input("desea continuar? s/n")
```

me falta eso, saber como hacer la ultima parte usando adecuadamente print. desde ya se agradece cualquier ayuda :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más simple es que uses `dict.items`  junto a `sorted`:

```
import operator

dic = {"a": 5, "d": 2, "c": 1, "b": 7}

for key, value in sorted(dic.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

Salida:

```
c: 1
d: 2
a: 5
b: 7
```

**Explicación**:

- `dict.items` es un método de los diccionarios que genera una vista del mismo, un iterable con las parejas clave-valor. Para nuestro ejemplo podemos representarlo como:

  ```
  [('a', 5), ('d', 2), ('c', 1), ('b', 7)]
  ```
- [`sorted(iterable, *, key=None, reverse=False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted): esta función preconstruida retorna una lista con los items ordenar un iterable, el argumento `key` permite definir una función que recibe cada item como argumento y su retorno se usa para ordenar. Lo anterior es similar a algo así:

  ```
  dic = {"a": 5, "d": 2, "c": 1, "b": 7}

  def ordenar_por_segundo_item(iterable):
      return iterable[1]

  for key, value in sorted(dic.items(), key=ordenar_por_segundo_item):
      print(f"{key}: {value}")
  ```

  `operator.itemgetter` hace la función de `ordenar_por_segundo_item`, solo que de forma más eficiente, a nivel de código C compilado.

  `sorted` básicamente toma la "lista" `[('a', 5), ('d', 2), ('c', 1), ('b', 7)]` retornada por `dict.items()`, itera sobre ella y por cada elemento (por ejemplo `('a', 5)`) llama a la función asociada a `key` y se lo pasa como argumento y usa su retorno (`5` en éste caso) para ordenar la lista de tuplas, obteniendo:

  ```
  [('c', 1), ('d', 2), ('a', 5), ('b', 7)]
  ```
- Hecho esto solo tenemos que usar un `for` para recorrerla. Las variables `key` y `value` toman en cada iteración el primer elemento de la tupla y el segundo respectivamente (desempaquetado), por lo que solo tenemos que imprimirlas.

  `f"{key}: {value}"` es un literal de cadena formateado, básicamente sustituye la expresión que hay dentro de toda pareja de `{}` por el valor resultado de evaluarla. Esto **está disponible a partir de Python 3.6**, solo. Si no es tu caso puedes hacer por ejemplo: `print("{}: {}".format(key, value))`.

---

**Extra**

En Python, los diccionarios tradicionalmente no han mantenido el orden de inserción, por lo que no se pueden ordenar internamente (necesidad de usar `collections.OrderedDict` para ello). A partir de Python 3.6 (como detalle de implemetación solo) y Python 3.7 (definitivamente) los diccionarios mantienen siempre su orden de inserción original, lo cual se extiende a sus vistas.

Si una vez creado el diccionario no vas a actualizarlo pero vas a iterar asíduamente sobre él con la necesidad de que esté ordenado, puedes ordenarlo cuando lo creas directamente evitando tener que llamar a `sorted` cada vez. Obviamente si actualizas tendrás que volverlo a ordenar.

```
partido_y_votos = sorted(partido_y_votos.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

A partir de este momento y mientras no lo modifique el diccionario estará ordenado según sus valores, para imprimirlo ordenado las veces que quieras basta con:

```
for key, value in partido_y_votos.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

Comment: no soy muy experimentado en python, me podes explicar un poco la linea: for key, value in sorted(dic.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):

Comment: @TomiBegher editada agregando algunas explicaciones, si te quedan dudas comenta.

Comment: buenisima explicación, espero que se pueda hacer "imports" en el parcial jajaj. Aparte de eso, si la lista quiero que sea de mayor a menor, donde iria el reverse? lo intento meter y me da error...

Comment: @TomiBegher  eso es el argumento `reverse` de `sorted`, basta con hacer `sorted(dic.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`. En cuanto a los "imports": [import essay](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/6a59fw/import_essay/?depth=1). Ya en serio, siempre puedes substituir itemgetter por una función commo la que muestro o anónima `key=lambda x: x[1]`, lo que no podrás es importar StackOverflow XD. Un saludo.

Comment: todos tus aportes fueron utiles, pero para alguien como yo que empezo a aprender hace poco mas de 1 mes, todavia tengo que mantenerlo simple y cuanto menos imports use mejor... lo solucione usando parte de lo que dijiste y me quedo algo asi:`lista = sorted(partido_y_votos.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)` y
`for x in lista: 
    print("el partido",x[0],"tuvo",x[1],"votos")` Muchas gracias, te llevaste manito arriba y mejor respuesta :)

Answer (score 1):

## CICLO FOR

Te comparto tu codigo con lo que necesitabas, en cada linea deje un comentario explicando lo que hice, lo mas importante es que con un "for" obteniamos todas las key y con estas se puede mandar a llamar a su valor ("partido_y_votos[variable_utilizada_en_el_for]")

```
partido_y_votos = {}
continuar = "s"
while continuar == "s":
    partido_politico = input("ingrese partido politico: ")
    cantidad_votos = int(input("ingrese cantidad de votos del partido: "))

# agrega el nombre del partido y sus votos al diccionario.
# si el nombre se repite, se suman los votos ingresados

    if partido_politico in partido_y_votos: #si partido ya esta en el diccionario hacer lo siguiente
        partido_y_votos[partido_politico] += cantidad_votos #si ya esta entonces agregarle mas votos
    else: #si es un nuevo partido
        partido_y_votos[partido_politico] = cantidad_votos #ingresar los datos
    continuar = input("desea continuar? s/n") #salir o seguir

  
for key in partido_y_votos: #Obtenemos la key de cada elemento dentro del diccionario 
    print("*" * 50)
    print("El partido '{}' tiene {} votos".format(key,partido_y_votos[key])) # el .format es una forma de concatenar

#con la key podemos mandar a llamar su valor de esta forma partido_y_votos[key]
```